# Problem sorting R data frame in descending order

Tags: r

I don't know why I can't sort descending in this dataframe.

My dataframe is org.

```
names(org)
```

[1] "...1"        "user_id"     "notes"       "type"        "type2"       "arts"
 [7] "music"       "tourism"     "name"        "contact"     "email"       "email2"
[13] "website"     "phone"       "address"     "city"        "state"       "zipcode"
[19] "page_exists" "image"       "description" "photo"       "doc"         "page_name"

```
newdata <- org[order(page_exists, image),]
```

works fine, but

```
newdata <- org[order(-page_exists, image),]
```

creates an error:

Error in -page_exists : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Are you sure `org[order(page_exists, image),]` works ? Try `org[with(org, order(-page_exists, image)), ]`

Comment: same problem:  org[with(org, order(page_exists, image)), ]  works fine; org[with(org, order(-page_exists, image)), ]  does not.

Comment: >     x = org[with(org, order(-page_exists, image)), ] 
Error in -page_exists : invalid argument to unary operator
>     x = org[with(org, order(page_exists, image)), ] 
>     cat("done")
done
>

Comment: Is there an alternative to "order"?

Comment: Using `dplyr`, `org %>% arrange(desc(page_exists), image)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `page_exists` is not a numeric column, so `-page_exists` doesn't work.  You can use the obscurely named `xtfrm` function to convert it to one, so this should work:

```
org[with(org, order(-xtfrm(page_exists), image)), ]
```

If you forget that name, this will also work (but is probably a little slower):

```
org[with(org, order(-rank(page_exists), image)), ]
```

Comment: That works... Is there no function in r to sort a dataframe by a string variable?

Comment: Both `sort()` and `order()` work fine on string variables.  They both sort into ascending order.  My answer is one way to get them to sort into descending order.  You can also tell them to put all columns into descending order.